# How to call super constructor with params from abstract class if current class is spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two classes from custom library, that i can't change. Bass class have only constructor with custom param, that's not a bean. I want to pass param via child constructor, but i have no idea how to do that, so please help)

I tried this, but doesn't work. Idea underline param in Child constructor.

```
@Bean
public ChildClass childClass() {
    return new ChildClass(new CustomParam(5));
}
```

Base class- can't use `@Component`, that class from library

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

private CustomParam customParam;

protected BaseClass(CustomParam customParam) {
    this.customParam = customParam;
}

public Integer getCustomParam() {
    return customParam.getParamValue();
}
}
```

Child class. My own extension

```
@Component
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

//idea underline customParam "could not autowire"
public ChildClass(CustomParam customParam) {
    super(customParam);
}
}
```

Param class- can't use `@Component`, that class from library

```
public class CustomParam {
private Integer paramValue;

public CustomParam(Integer paramValue) {
    this.paramValue = paramValue;
}

public Integer getParamValue() {
    return paramValue;
}

public void setParamValue(Integer paramValue) {
    this.paramValue = paramValue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CustomParam` need not to be annotated with `@Component` annotation, still you can declare it as bean using`@Bean` annotation

**Config class**

```
@Bean
public ChildClass childClass() {
    return new ChildClass(customParam());
 }

  @Bean
public CustomParam customParam() {
    return new CustomParam(5);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know why you would want to use the CustomParam which is just an int wrapper as bean.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you instantiate your bean like this you don't need the @Component annotation on your ChildClass. Make sure your bean definition is in a configurationclass (@Configuration) and your config is part of the component scan.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public BaseClass childClass() {
        return new ChildClass(new CustomParam(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with another way? It's a common usage to define your beans via a configuration class and not with the Service or Component annotation.